# whether there is any tutorial for android zxing library with Fragments

Tags: android, zxing

I'm looking for some tutorial or sample how to use Zxing library within android's Fragment.

UPDATE:

Using IntentIntegratorSupportV4 can I use only scanner if it installed on device or in my own app? 
Because I want to use QR Scanner in my own app which has two tabs. In fist must be this scanner. How I can handle it?

Comment: There is no "Zxing library", last I checked. Do you mean their `IntentIntegrator` class?

Comment: Yes. Especially I want to use IntentIntegratorSupportV4. But I don't how work with it. Maybe you know some samples or tutorial? I have found only this: [link](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/ZXing) demonstrates the use of `IntentIntegrator`, and you will find a compiled JAR containing that class in the project's `libs/` directory.

There are really only two steps:

1. Call `(new IntentIntegrator(this)).initiateScan();` to bring up the scanner.
2. Implement `onActivityResult()` and use `IntentIntegrator` to help parse the results:

   ```
   public void onActivityResult(int request, int result, Intent i) {
       IntentResult scan=IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(request, result, i);

       if (scan!=null) {
           format.setText(scan.getFormatName());
           contents.setText(scan.getContents());
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I have done this but my app give me notification: "Install Barcode Scanner? this app requires Barcode Scanner...."

Comment: @vovaxo: Correct. That is what it is supposed to do, for users who do not have the app installed. As I wrote in my comment on your question, there is no ZXing library. Barcode Scanner is an app -- `IntentIntegrator` helps you integrate with that app.

Comment: @vovaxo: "Because I want to use QR Scanner in my own app which has two tabs. In fist must be this scanner. How I can handle it?" -- that is not supported by the ZXing team. It is also an fairly strange UI design, IMHO.

Comment: If want to use ZXing library in my app what should I do?

Comment: @vovaxo: I have written this twice. You are ignoring it. Let me try boldface caps: **THERE IS NO ZXING LIBRARY**. I repeat, *there is no ZXing library*. You are welcome to take the ZXing open source code and attempt to embed it in your app, but you will be on your own for this, as the ZXing does not support this approach.

Comment: Okey. Are there some some examples how customize Zxing source code to use it in own app. I am beginner in android and I don't know how to this. I have tried to use Zxing class CaptureActivity it appears as I need but how can I receive result of scanning? (startActivityForResult)

Comment: @vovaxo: "Are there some some examples how customize Zxing source code to use it in own app" -- no official ones. Again, this is not supported by the ZXing team. "I am beginner in android and I don't know how to this" -- to be honest, it would be at least a bit of a challenge for me, and I have been doing Android development for 4.5 years, have written books on the subject, etc. I *strongly* encourage you to redesign your UI such that you can use `IntentIntegrator`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sir, Is it possible to show this scanner inside a fragment, instead to taking whole screen as Activity? `.initiateScan` seems to return a dialog. Can this be utilized to show it inside a fragment somehow? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: @ShobhitPuri: `initiateScan()` launches Barcode Scanner, which is another application. Another application cannot reside in one of your fragments.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks again. Any alternative for making that possible? You must have seen some apps showing an scanner inside a fragment.

Comment: @ShobhitPuri: Find a library. ZXing is an app (Barcode Scanner) and interface to that app (IntentIntegrator JAR). It is not a library.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tutorial on integrating it into your own app. Although this is not recommended

http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/